# How to divide ul (li) into columns in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a ul section generated in a Django template:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And I want to divide it to columns containing for example 10 elements. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I want to divide it to columns containing for example 10 elements. How do I do it?

Did you mean "Divide into 10 columns" or "Divide into *n* columns, containing no more than 10 rows each"? It's often better to fix the number of columns (since horizontal space tends to be limited). Either way, you can do this with a custom template tag, like so:

```
from django import template
from itertools import chain, izip
import math

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def colgroup(parser, token):
    """
    Usage:: {% colgroup items into 3 cols as grouped_items %}

    <table border="0">
        {% for row in grouped_items %}
        <tr>
            {% for item in row %}
            <td>{% if item %}{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}. {{ item }}{% endif %}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    Outputs::
    ============================================
    | 1. One   | 1. Eleven   | 1. Twenty One   |
    | 2. Two   | 2. Twelve   | 2. Twenty Two   |
    | 3. Three | 3. Thirteen | 3. Twenty Three |
    | 4. Four  | 4. Fourteen |                 |
    ============================================
    """
    class Node(template.Node):
        def __init__(self, iterable, num_cols, varname):
            self.iterable = iterable
            self.num_cols = num_cols
            self.varname = varname

        def render(self, context):
            iterable = template.Variable(self.iterable).resolve(context)
            num_cols = self.num_cols
            context[self.varname] = izip(*[chain(iterable, [None]*(num_cols-1))] * num_cols)
            return u''

    try:
        _, iterable, _, num_cols, _, _, varname = token.split_contents()
        num_cols = int(num_cols)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Invalid arguments passed to %r." % token.contents.split()[0])
    return Node(iterable, num_cols, varname)
```

Most of this should be familiar if you're familiar with [Django's Custom Template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best descision is to use **css3 columns feature** for that task - it would have a *better semantics* and SEO-guys would be glad :)

Modern browsers already can split your li's into columns.

I solved the same problem like this:

```
.columns-x {
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;

    column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;    
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Okay, and what about old browsers? I used [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to get if broser supports css3-columns. If it does not - I use [jquery-columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

So, here is what I do in my html:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    Modernizr.load({
        test:Modernizr.csscolumns,
        yep:'{{ STATIC_URL }}_b/columns/css/columns-pure.css', // this is .columns-x - you've seen it above
        nope:[ 
             // load columnizer plugin
            '{{ STATIC_URL }}_b/columns/js/jquery.columnizer.min.js', 
            //  tell it what to do
            '{{ STATIC_URL }}_b/columns/js/columns-trick.js'
        ]
    })
</script>
```

And here is what I tell columnizer to do (columns-trick.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.columns-x').columnize({columns: 3});
});
```